# PDO out of memory in Zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo, host

i have a drop down that needs to be filled with data fetched from database. the problem is there is a huge amount of rows in database that need to be fetched and PDO gives me this error `Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 396043 bytes) in /home/myild/domains/myild.ir/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 290`
i am working on zend 1.2 framework. i also contacted my host provider and he increased memory limit.
note: set ini is blocked on the host.

Comment: Thats a gig of memory you are using. There must be some arrays you could release once you have finished with them allowing PHP to free memory

Comment: A query that returns that many results is probably gonna make for one heck of a long dropdown...

Comment: yes it a very huge nested tree for selecting an item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the issue...
Zend fetch All reads the whole data and wants to write them to memory all at once.so best approch is to use a loop and fetchRow method and then create the result on fly.